# Waiting for a HTTP request

Tags: scala, http

I am looking at this tutorial: http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-http-requests/.

I'm trying to make a plain HTTP request like the one they have:

```
  val address = url("http://somewebaddress.com/elements")
  val x = Http(address OK as.String)
```

However, for that part of the code I am getting:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (com.ning.http.client.Request, dispatch.OkFunctionHandler[String])
[error]  required: akka.actor.ActorSystem
[error]       val x = Http(address OK as.String)
[error]                            ^
```

Which is quite strange since I'm passing only 1 argument, not 2.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you can try to specity the output parameter Future[String]

Comment: Check your imports

Answer (score 0):

I was importing another HTTP library by accident and there was a name clash.

Answer (score -2):

You have typo error in this string:

```
val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)
```

Comment: I don't see this in the original question, can you please rephrase by quoting the line you think should be changed?